# how to create embedded browser in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

The user needs to browse sites through the Java program (not netbeans IDE), it should behave exactly like FireFox browser or IE, any suggestions ? I need to be able to access the DOM so I can manipulate DOM elements.

Also, is there something equivalent to Perl's CPAN but for Java ?

Answer (score 0):

ugh, i've done something like this a while back in ... c++ i think. that must have been in 2002 or something like that. i used a component from Borland's C++ Builder back then (or did i use delphi?) anyways, i did a quick google search and found a rather antique post from '99; if nothing else, it's perhaps a good place to start.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip66.html

you may also want to look at http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t682627-embedding-web-browser-prefer-firefox-in-java-application.html

i hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

check out http://www.mozilla.org/projects/blackwood/webclient/